# Нужна помощь в модификации скрипта!

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**ДВС Господа**!
Нужна помощь в модификации скрипта!
Человек писавший данный скрипт с нового года не выходит на связь!
Попытаюсь максимально корректно описать суть проблемы.
Сам скрипт:

```
    let timerId=setInterval(function(){
      var day='08';
      var month='02';
      var year='2022';
      var hour='23';

      $.ajax({
          url: 'https://site.com/calendar/word?date='+day+'.'+month+'.'+year,
          type: 'GET',
          //dataType: 'json',
          //data: {case: 'ajax_progress'},
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        console.log('look');
          if(data.match(/int inAvail/)){
            console.log('OK');
            clearTimeout(timerId);
            var date=day+'_'+month+'_'+year+'_'+hour;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {date:date},
                url: '/calendar/times/chspk',
                //dataType: object['dataType'],
                success: function(data){
                    //console.log(data);
                    console.log(document.cookie);
                    console.log(localStorage);
                    document.location='https://site.com/calendar/nextreg';
                }
            });
          }
      })
    }, 1000);
```

**Прилагаю к скрипту небольшой кусок HTML кода с сайта:**

```
    <div data-int="08_02_2022_13" class="int intFull "> <div>13-14</div></div> 
    <div data-int="08_02_2022_14" class="int intFull "> <div>14-15</div></div>
    <div data-int="08_02_2022_15" class="int intFull "> <div>15-16</div></div>
    <div data-int="08_02_2022_16" class="int intFull "> <div>16-17</div></div>
    <div data-int="08_02_2022_17" class="int intFull "> <div>17-18</div></div>
    <div data-int="08_02_2022_18" class="int intFull "> <div>18-19</div></div>
    <div data-int="08_02_2022_19" class="int intFull "> <div>19-20</div></div>
    <div data-int="08_02_2022_20" class="int intFull "> <div>20-21</div></div>
    <div data-int="08_02_2022_21" class="int intFull "> <div>21-22</div></div>
    <div data-int="08_02_2022_22" class="int intFull "> <div>22-23</div></div>
    <div data-int="08_02_2022_23" class="int intFull "> <div>23-00</div></div>
```

Как видите и вы уже поняли, данный скрипт выполняется из под консоли браузера на сайте.
Скрипт отслеживает изменение класса, как только допустим блок с интервалом **data-int="08_02_2022_23"** становится такого вида:

```
    <div data-int="08_02_2022_23" class="int intlAvail ">   <div>23-00</div></div>
```

И как только скрипт находит изменение **class="int intlAvail"**, он отправляет **POST** запрос:
***date=08_02_2022_23***
И вроде бы все хорошо и все отлично, все устраивает. НО
Есть одно НО
В данном JS изначально задается параметр **var hour='23';** в котором я задаю нужный мне интервал времени.
Соответственно получается скрипт изначально заточен под определенный интервал времени.
И очень часто происходит не верная отправка POST
А происходит это по тому что:
Класс ****class="int intlAvail"**** иногда появляется совершенно в другом временном интервале.
Например:

```
    <div data-int="08_02_2022_13" class="int intlAvail ">   <div>13-14</div></div>
```

Соответственно доступный интервал становится **08_02_2022_13** а скрипт отправляет POST с интервалом **08_02_2022_23**.
После отправки не верного POST, на сайте прилетает бан аккаунта мгновенно!

***В общем то, что я хочу:***
Хотелось бы конечно увидеть **2 варианта** скрипта если они вообще возможны в данном случае.

1. Вариант который бы очень уж хотелось бы реализовать, это что бы скрипт не привязывался ко временному интервалу вообще.
   т.е. что бы после его запуска он как и прежде отслеживал изменение класса **/int inAvail/** во всех блоках div.
   Но хотелось бы что бы он сам выдергивал нужный интервал из блока и подставлял его в POST запрос
   Например
   Появился в блоке класс **int inAvail**

   ```html
       <div data-int="08_02_2022_17" class="int intFull "> <div>17-18</div></div>
       <div data-int="08_02_2022_18" class="int intFull "> <div>18-19</div></div>
       <div data-int="08_02_2022_19" class="int intlAvail ">   <div>19-20</div></div>
       <div data-int="08_02_2022_20" class="int intFull "> <div>20-21</div></div>
   ```

Нужно что бы скрипт выдернул значение **08_02_2022_19** и подставил его в POST запрос.
Не знаю конечно реализуемо это вообще или нет... но уж очень сильно хотелось бы **: (**

2. Вариант который хотелось бы реализовать, это что бы скрипт прям конкретно привязать ко временному интервалу.
   Например:
   Если я в скрипте указываю **var hour='19';**
   То что бы он конкретно отслеживал мне этот div на изменение класса **intlAvail**

```html
<div data-int="08_02_2022_19" class="int intFull "> <div>19-20</div></div>
```

Даже если в другом DIV'e появится **intlAvail**, что бы скрипт не отправлял ложный POST.
Народ, был бы очень сильно вам благодарен за помощь.
При каждом застолье **5 раз подряд** выпивал бы за ВАШЕ ЗДОРОВЬЕ !!! // Шутка конечно, но пару раз бы точно выпил : )))
В общем народ, выручайте! Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: По моему проблема описана более чем конкретно! ))